# freeswitch noob cant build solution

Tags: visual-studio, freeswitch

im just starting out with FreeSwitch, i downloaded via git, and am trying to build in VS

all i need i believe are the dlls of mod_managed, as my goal is to manage FS via .net

but i get 248 errors, most look something like this:

Error 5 error C1083: Cannot open source file: '....\jpeg-8d\jaricom.c': No such file or directory D:\FreeSwitch\freeswitch\libs\win32\libjpeg\c1 libjpeg

btw, i searched windows and cannot find any such file anywhere on my pc.

**I tried**

- cleaning the solution first, but it did not help
- moving the file to a path without spaces
- downloading with autocrlf=false
- building on another machine

but none of these steps helped

anybody have any idea?

if i can just download the dlls i need, i wouldnt mind skipping this step altogether

*environment*

- win 8 64bit
- visual studio 2012

thanks a million

Comment: Well does that file actually exist or not? If yes, could be that the project file is not in the correct location, maybe if you move it to the correct relative path it'll find everything..

Comment: hi thanks. nope it does not exist anywhere on my pc. any other ideas?

Comment: is that the *exact* error message you get? That it cannot find `c1`?? Anyway there's something off with your system: I just cloned https://github.com/FreeSWITCH/FreeSWITCH.git, opened Freeswitch.2012.sln, built it and the result was `Build: 167 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 15 skipped` in other words: all fine

Comment: thats the exact message yes. i copied it from vs. did you have the jaricom.c file *before* build? it looks like thats whats its looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libjpeg sources are not in the git sources but are normally downloaded during the build process. If you build the entire solution that should not be a problem since it has the project dependencies set: `libjpeg.2012` depends on `Download libjpg.2012`, which means the latter gets built before the first. All `Download libjpg.2012` is run a `cscript` which downloads libjpeg from http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8d.tar.gz (see inside the project file).

So if you do not have the sources, either you are building incorrectly (not in VS for instance, or with a broken solution file) or the download script is broken. In that case, you should inspect the output: I assume it shows errors when it can not download the libs.

Comment: thanks a million! adding those domains to my web filter exceptions did the trick. im new to git and didn't think anything was getting download as part of a build. thanks!